# datetime.fromtimestamp() takes longer than datetime.utcfromtimestamp()

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, datetime, timestamp

I have written a statistics / ML program that performs some data analysis on Time Series data. Surprisingly, when I get timestamps using the `fromtimestamp()` method, my program executes in roughly 15 seconds, whereas when using the `utcfromtimestamp()`, it executes in a second or less.

To test and compare their runtimes, I ran a python program:

```
timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()

start = datetime.now()
date1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(datetime.now() - start)

start = datetime.now()
date2 = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(datetime.now() - start)
```

But I found `fromtimestamp()` to be consistently faster in this case.

```
Runtime of fromtimestamp - 00.000004
Approx Runtime of utcfromtimestamp - 0.000267
```

In my program though, `fromtimestamp()` takes roughly `0.4` seconds.

Are there some hidden factors at play here? Note, in my ML program I do threading, and multiprocessing. I'm not sure if that may be the factor at play here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden factor is that `datetime.fromtimestamp()` produces **local time**. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp

while `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` returns UTC time:

> Return the UTC datetime corresponding to the POSIX timestamp

A POSIX timestamp represents time in UTC, *always*. So it is much simpler to convert that number into a UTC `datetime` object (no timezone conversion required) versus having to look up the system timezone and then applying the timezone adjustments required.

The difference between the functions basically comes down to using [`time.localtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime) vs [`time.gmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime), which are covered by the [`localtime_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) / [`gmtime_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime_r) functions (on POSIX systems) or the [`localtime_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-s-localtime32-s-localtime64-s) / [`gmtime_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gmtime-s-gmtime32-s-gmtime64-s) functions (on Windows).

Your timing test is otherwise badly flawed. Use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to run time trials:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import timeit
>>> timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
>>> timeit.timeit("datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)", "from __main__ import datetime, timestamp")
0.6479804780101404
>>> timeit.timeit("datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)", "from __main__ import datetime, timestamp")
0.2666302509896923
```

This shows `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` to be faster, consistently.

Comment: However, it consistently runs faster (on one thread). Is it accessing some system which has a lock and thus slows down the process during multithreading? I'm sorry I'm not convinced seeing the runtime printed from my python program.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj: no, your timing test is just flawed, sorry.

Comment: Oh! Wow, it's very inaccurate. I'll search up why. Thanks a lot.